# How can I use a static method as a default parameter for the strategy design pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods, strategy-pattern, default-parameters

I want to make a class that uses a strategy design pattern similar to this:

```
class C:

    @staticmethod
    def default_concrete_strategy():
        print("default")

    @staticmethod
    def other_concrete_strategy():
        print("other")

    def __init__(self, strategy=C.default_concrete_strategy):
        self.strategy = strategy

    def execute(self):
        self.strategy()
```

This gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

Replacing `strategy=C.default_concrete_strategy` with `strategy=default_concrete_strategy` will work but, left as default, the strategy instance variable will be a static method object rather than a callable method.

```
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

It will work if I remove the `@staticmethod` decorator, but is there some other way? I want the default parameter to be self documented so that others will immediately see an example of how to include a strategy.

Also, is there a better way to expose strategies rather than as static methods? I don't think that implementing full classes makes sense here.

Comment: The strategy pattern is mostly useless in python. Since you have functions as first class objects you can just pass functions around.

Comment: @Bakuriu Well as you can see the strategy is a first class object function. I think this is still called a strategy pattern no?

Comment: Yes, but the strategy pattern was mostly invented in languages that do not allow functions to be passed around. What I mean is that in 99% of the use cases of your class you can simply pass the function directly and obtain the same results with less complexity.

Comment: @Bakuriu can you please give an example of how this can be done?

Comment: Also related to question [_Calling class staticmethod within the class body?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you cannot, because the `class` definition has not yet completed running so the class name doesn't exist yet in the current namespace.

You *can* use the function object directly:

```
class C:    
    @staticmethod
    def default_concrete_strategy():
        print("default")

    @staticmethod
    def other_concrete_strategy():
        print("other")

    def __init__(self, strategy=default_concrete_strategy.__func__):
        self.strategy = strategy
```

`C` doesn't exist yet when the methods are being defined, so you refer to `default_concrete_strategy` by the local name. `.__func__` unwraps the `staticmethod` descriptor to access the underlying original function (a `staticmethod` descriptor is not itself callable).

Another approach would be to use a sentinel default; `None` would work fine here since all normal values for `strategy` are static functions:

```
class C:    
    @staticmethod
    def default_concrete_strategy():
        print("default")

    @staticmethod
    def other_concrete_strategy():
        print("other")

    def __init__(self, strategy=None):
        if strategy is None:
            strategy = self.default_concrete_strategy
        self.strategy = strategy
```

Since this retrieves `default_concrete_strategy` from `self` the descriptor protocol is invoked and the (unbound) function is returned by the `staticmethod` descriptor itself, well after the class definition has completed.

Comment: Or he could first define `default_concrete_strategy` *without* decorating it, and then decorate it after the definition of `__init__` (as decorators were used before 2.4), although this would be quite cumbersome.

Comment: @Bakuriu: exactly; much easier to just unwrap.

Comment: It's a shame if this is the only way. It would have been nice to see an example directly in the code of how to pass a parameter.

@Bakuriu would decorating a method in the constructor be helpful?

Comment: @mtanti No. you have to put the `@staticmethod` in the class. I meant something like `def method():pass;  def __init__(self, func=method):pass; method = staticmethod(method)`. However I must say that I'd prefer simply use `None` as default value and check for it in the `__init__`.

Comment: @mtanti: no, because descriptors need to be set on objects **on the class** not on the instance.

Comment: @mtanti: it is not the only way, but it is the most readable way. The alternative is to apply the decorator 'by hand'; define `default_concrete_strategy` **without** the `@staticmethod` line, then after you defined the `__init__` method, use `default_concrete_strategy = staticmethod(default_concrete_strategy)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I didn't know you could decorate a method like that. Interesting.

Comment: @mtanti: `@expression` followed by a class or function definition is nothing more than syntactic sugar for `name_of_obj = expression(name_of_obj)` *after* the class or function definition has completed.

Comment: I don't think it's made clear in the answer but you have to **place the default_concrete_strategy staticmethod ABOVE the function you would like to execute the method in as parameter**, in this case the `__init__` function. Great tip otherwise thanks! Used the `.__func__` solution for a non-init method for a class I was creating.

Comment: @decoder247 that’s because function defaults are executed when the function is created, not when it is being called. So the name `default_concrete_strategy` must exist in the class scope when `def __init__(...):` is being executed to create the function object.