# How to call static method by reference?

Tags: python, static-methods, invoke

Please see the following example:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def __myStaticMethod(someArgs):
        pass

    MY_SPECIAL_METHOD_LIST = [
        __myStaticMethod
    ]

    @staticmethod
    def someOtherMethod():
        m = MyClass.MY_SPECIAL_METHOD_LIST[0]
        print(m)
        m()
```

If I now execute the statement `MyClass.someOtherMethod()` I get an exception:

```
<staticmethod object at 0x7fd672e69898>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test3.py", line 25, in <module>
    MyClass.someOtherMethod()
  File "./test3.py", line 21, in someOtherMethod
    m()
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Obviously `m` contains a reference to the static method. But I can not call this method. Why? What do I need to change in order to call this method?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body

Comment: @haffla: very good find. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting. I searched for an answer but did not come across that one. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call a static method from inside your class you need to unwrap it. change `m()` to `m.__func__('params')` and you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.