# Accessing a static method or attribute from a static attribute in Python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to access a static method or attribute when assigning to a static attribute?

For example:

```
class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def fortytwo():
        return 42

    var = Test.fortytwo()
```

would raise `NameError: name 'Test' is not defined`

Comment: You can't do that with `@staticmethod` but it works if you 1. omit `@staticmethod` and  2.call `fortytwo()` instead of `Test.fortytwo()`.

Comment: You can also just do it outside the class body: `Test.var = Test.fortytwo()`.

Comment: @natonomo Are you aware that var = Test.fortytwo() is defined inside the class due to the indent?

Comment: @MichaelScheffenacker yes that was the idea. The class this example represents is entirely static methods and attributes. I know the methods can access the attributes, I was hoping the opposite was true.

Comment: And the link at the top (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718272/2534715) did also not help you out?

Comment: @natonomo a class with only static methods and attributes probably shouldn't be a class. The fundamental problem, though, is as implied by the error message, *the class object doesn't exist until the class definition is finished executing*. You cannot access the class namespace because it hasn't been created yet. You can just do it after the class definition though.

Comment: @MichaelScheffenacker no it did, I'm not sure why I couldn't find that when I was forming this question. I decided to convert the "static class" to a module, as that is the Pythonic way