# How to initialize a class variable with a static method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

```
class A:
    x = A.initX()

    def __init__(self):
        self.y = A.initY()

    @staticmethod
    def initX():
        return 'X'

    @staticmethod
    def initY():
        return 'Y'
```

In the example above, I am not able to initialize the class `A` attribute `X`.
The PyCharm editor is complaining of `Unresolved reference 'A'`. However, there does not seem to be a problem with initializing the instance attribute of `Y` using a similar way.

How do I initialize a class attribute using a static method from the same class?

Comment: You can't (not from within `A` at least). Class attributes are defined at class definition time. As such, when `x = A.initX()` is executed, `A` does not "fully" exist yet, hence the error you recieve

Comment: Run `A.x = A.initX()` after the whole definition of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very similar to one I once asked titled [Calling class staticmethod within the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body). @DeepSpace's comment about how a class not existing during `class` definition time is the reason why.

Here's how to adapt the accepted answer to my question to your own situation (to define the class attribute within the class definition itself):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = A.initY()

    @staticmethod
    def initX():
        return 'X'

    @staticmethod
    def initY():
        return 'Y'

    x = initX.__func__()  # Define class attribute.


print(A.x)  # -> X
```

As @Klaus D. commented, another way to do it is after the class is defined (outside the class body).

You don't encounter the problem initializing the instance attribute of `Y` because it occurs within a method of an *instance* of the class (so the class is fully defined at that point).