# Call class or static method from static initialization block in python

Tags: python, class, constructor, static, initialization

I want to run a static/class function from a python class' "initialization block" (and not from the `__init__` constructor).

```
from . import config as cfg

class MyHandler():
    key_vault_client = SecretClient(cfg.kv_conf)
    credential, storage_client = MyHandler.initialize_storage_client()
    
    @classmethod
    def initialize_storage_client(cls):
        # check some constraints
        credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id = cfg.client_id,
            client_secret = cls.get_secret(cfg.storage_client_secret),
            tenant_id = cfg.tenant_id
        )
        storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, cfg.subscription_id)
        return credential, storage_client 

    @classmethod
    def get_secret(cls, secret_name):
        return cls.key_vault_client.get_secret(secret_name).value
```

But I've realized that I can't call a static/class or any method (which would give my `credential` and `storage_client` variables the values in the above case) from a block which is the static initialization block in Java.
Notice that the `initialize_storage_client()` calls the `get_secret()` method for secrets.

If I can do something like this:

```
class MagicalHandler():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_prop_1 = "object_prop_1_value"
        self.object_prop_2 = self.get_object_prop_value()
    
    def get_object_prop_value(self):
        return "object_prop_2_value"
    
x = MagicalHandler()
print(x.object_prop_1)
print(x.object_prop_2)
```

Then why I can't do something like this:

```
class MagicalHandler():
    
    @classmethod
    def get_class_prop_value(cls):
        return "object_prop_2_value"
    
    class_prop_1 = "class_prop_1_value"
    class_prop_2 = MagicalHandler.get_class_prop_value()

print(MagicalHandler.class_prop_1)
print(MagicalHandler.class_prop_2)
```

or this:

```
class MagicalHandler():
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_class_prop_value():
        return "object_prop_2_value"
    
    class_prop_1 = "class_prop_1_value"
    class_prop_2 = MagicalHandler.get_class_prop_value()

print(MagicalHandler.class_prop_1)
print(MagicalHandler.class_prop_2)
```

What is the solution for the above problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body/12718272

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling class staticmethod within the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body)