# Python 3.9 - Passing Method When Initialising Static Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-variables

I was hoping to be able to do this:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, foo:Callable):
        self._foo = foo

class D:

    bar:'C' = C(D.ping) # Unresolved reference 'D'
    
    # I also tried this;
    # bar:'C' = C(ping) # Unresolved reference 'ping'

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def ping(self, pong:str):
        ...
```

I was surprised this didn't work.
Is this not possible?

You can obviously do this:

```py
...

class E:
    bar:'C' = C(D.ping)
    
    def __init__ ... #etc
```

This is a very similar question:
[Calling class staticmethod within the class body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body)

But perhaps different because they are trying to call a static method, while I am trying to pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could put `bar` definition after `ping` definition:

```
class D:
    print(locals())

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def ping(self, pong: str):
        ...

    print(locals())
    bar: 'C' = C(ping)
```

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'D', '__annotations__': {}}
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'D', '__annotations__': {}, '__init__': <function D.__init__ at 0x7f18f5de0e50>, 'ping': <function D.ping at 0x7f18f5de0ee0>}
```

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't think of that.