# decorator declared and used inside of class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I wrote a manager class to interact with Metabase and I wish to write a decorator inside this class to renew sessions if they're expired.

```py
import requests

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Callable, Any
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework import status

from core.service.logger import exceptionErrorLog
from core.service.sensetiveApi.parameterModel import Parameter


class MetabaseManager:
    """
    A manager class for interacting with Metabase

    Usage:
        metabaseManager = MetabaseManager()
        metabaseManager.getQuestion(questionId=34)

    Attributes:
        Parameter.METABASE_BASE_URL (str): The base url of the Metabase server
        Parameter.METABASE_USERNAME (str): The username to authenticate with Metabase
        Parameter.METABASE_PASSWORD (str): The password to authenticate with Metabase
        Parameter.METABASE_SESSION_ID (str): The session id provided by Metabase (no need to manually set this value)

    Methods:
        getQuestion(self, questionId: int) -> dict:
            Retrieves question data from Metabase
    """

    METABASE_SESSION_DURATION_IN_DAYS: int = 14

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.METABASE_BASE_URL: str = Parameter.objects.get(key=Parameter.METABASE_BASE_URL).value
        self.METABASE_USERNAME: str = Parameter.objects.get(key=Parameter.METABASE_USERNAME).value
        self.METABASE_PASSWORD: str = Parameter.objects.get(key=Parameter.METABASE_PASSWORD).value
        self.METABASE_HEADERS: dict = {}

    def _renewSession(self) -> None:
        now: datetime = timezone.now()
        url: str = urljoin(self.METABASE_BASE_URL, "/api/session/")
        response: requests.Response = requests.post(
            url=url,
            json={
                "username": self.METABASE_USERNAME,
                "password": self.METABASE_PASSWORD,
            },
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        sessionId: str = response.json()["id"]
        Parameter.objects(key=Parameter.METABASE_SESSION_ID).update(
            value=sessionId,
            createdAt=now,
            expireAt=now + timedelta(days=MetabaseManager.METABASE_SESSION_DURATION_IN_DAYS),
            upsert=True,
        )
        self.METABASE_HEADERS["X-Metabase-Session"] = sessionId

    @staticmethod
    def _renewSessionIfExpired(function: Callable) -> Callable:
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            sessionId: Parameter = Parameter.objects.filter(key=Parameter.METABASE_SESSION_ID).first()
            if (
                    sessionId is None or
                    sessionId.expireAt is None or
                    sessionId.expireAt <= timezone.now()
            ):
                self._renewSession()
            return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @_renewSessionIfExpired
    def getQuestion(self, questionId: int) -> dict:
        url: str = urljoin(self.METABASE_BASE_URL, f"api/card/{questionId}/query")
        response: requests.Response = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.METABASE_HEADERS)
        if response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED:
            self._renewSession()
            response: requests.Response = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.METABASE_HEADERS)
        data = response.json().get("data", {}).get("rows")
        return data
```

Now this doesn't work, throwing this error:

```py
Python 3.6.15 (default, Dec 21 2021, 12:28:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from core.service.metabaseManager import MetabaseManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/project/app/core/service/metabaseManager.py", line 27, in <module>
    class MetabaseManager:
  File "/opt/project/app/core/service/metabaseManager.py", line 88, in MetabaseManager
    def getQuestion(self, questionId: int) -> dict:
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

I can solve this if I use the decorator like this outside of the class:

```py
MetabaseManager.getQuestion = MetabaseManager._renewSessionIfExpired(MetabaseManager.getQuestion)
```

This works, but isn't what I want. For one thing, I want the `_renewSessionIfExpired` decorator to remain private and using it like this outside of the class definition doesn't seem the right thing to do. And it's not clean to me, because it separates the usage of the decorator from the function declaration and I have to remember which functions I want to use the decorator on. How can I change this so that this works?

```py
@_renewSessionIfExpired
def getQuestion(self, questionId: int) -> dict:
    url: str = urljoin(self.METABASE_BASE_URL, f"api/card/{questionId}/query")
    response: requests.Response = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.METABASE_HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED:
        self._renewSession()
        response: requests.Response = requests.post(url=url, headers=self.METABASE_HEADERS)
    data = response.json().get("data", {}).get("rows")
    return data
```

Python version: 3.6.15

Comment: Why not just move `def _renewSessionIfExpired(...)` to just above the class.

Comment: @quamrana Because inside the decorator, I call a function that belongs to the instance. `self._renewSession()`

Comment: Moreover about the `class` block - it doesn't actually have a "scope" or whatever distinction that you think this particular indentation might imply - all assignments there actually is shared with the global scope (which causes [this particular footgun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933)) - you can replicate the same problem you are seeing by moving everything inside `MetabaseManager` to the top level (e.g.) global scope. [This diagram](https://i.imgur.com/D68cdWA.png) shows a problems with scopes in Python where code the class block doesn't actually live a special class scope.

Comment: However, your code example will work perfectly fine in Python>=3.10, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718187/python-version-3-9-calling-class-staticmethod-within-the-class-body) for details (also related [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87848)).